# How to specify JMX port to use in Kafka 0.9/0.10 and not run into port conflict when running any of the command line commands?

Tags: apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform

First off, I'm not sure if this issue exists in the standard Kafka packaging. I'm using Kafka as packaged by Hortonworks in HDP 2.4

In HDP 2.3 and Kafka 0.8.2, I export JMX_PORT=9999 in Kafka environment /etc/kafka/conf/kafka-env.sh. All command line commands such /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh work fine.

Not so in HDP 2.4 and Kafka 0.9 or in HDP 2.5 and Kafka 0.10. No matter which port I set JMX_PORT to, any of the commands throw the following error:

Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9999; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed line 112 of `/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-run-class.sh` to the following:

```
if [  $JMX_PORT ] && [ -z "$ISKAFKASERVER" ]; then
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't hack your kafka-run-class.sh file it would be erased at the next update

in your `kafka-env.sh` you should put that (based on `kafka-run-class.sh`)

```
if [ "x$ISKAFKASERVER" == "xtrue" ]; then
   export JMX_PORT=16667
fi
```